# extjs - Placeholders in strings

Tags: extjs, replace, extjs4.2

I saw [here in the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/localization) that there is a placeholder notation like:

```
"El valor mínimo para este campo es de {0}"
```

But I didn't find the function that will do the replacement. I expect a function similar to `sprintf` in php to exist which allow to replace these strings like:

```
function_Im_looking_for("El valor mínimo para este campo es de {0}", 10);
```

that returns the string `"El valor mínimo para este campo es de 10"`.

How can that replacement be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.String.format('Hello {0}', 'Foo');`

It's worth noting that it doesn't attempt to do any formatting, just simple replacement. So you can't do something like `{0:d/m/Y}`